# Are iPhone Wireless Chargers Good for Batteries?

Tags: iphone, charging, charger

I heard that the external wireless iPhone chargers for the XS MAX are not good for for the battery. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Do you have any specific sources that say wireless chargers are bad for iPhone batteries?

Comment: I read somewhere about wireless chargers are hard on batteries. I think it was in the Wall Street Journal or our local paper the Review Journal (Las Vegas, NV)

Answer (score 1):

Wireless charging is neither good nor bad for batteries; it's just an alternate way of getting the magic pixies (electrons) back into their cage (battery).  This is analogous to asking whether the interstate or the turnpike is better for your car. Both will get you to the same destination, but there are trade-offs from one to the other (i.e. the turnpike may be more direct, but they charge a toll where as the interstate is free, but it meanders around)

[image] 
<sup>Source:  [Mouser Electronics](https://www.mouser.com)</sup>

Above is a generic block schematic of a wireless charging circuit with an external charger.  Even though the charger is "outside" the device, it's still connected into the charging circuit to the Line Drop Out circuit/chip and the battery.  What that does is regulate where the device gets it's charge from - if it's "high", it will get the power from the charger.  If "low," it will get it from the wireless coil.  But in the end, there's only one destination - the battery charging circuit.

**A better question is....What works for *you*?**

- Wireless charging is slower but more convenient.
- USB/Power Adapter charging is faster, but you're tethered to something.
- Wireless charging has an inherent cool factor
- Wired charging is tried and true
- There's no connectors to wear out with wireless chargers
- Wired chargers securely connect (you don't have to put it in just the right spot) connect

Basically, it boils down to what is a better solution for your personal requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that charging in itself is "good" for batteries, but it's definitely not bad for the batteries.

Apple hasn't rated the batteries for a different life time when using wireless chargers compared to wired charger.

For all practical purposes, wireless charging is not "bad" for your batteries.

Answer (score 0):

**Wireless charging has the same effect on battery health as wired charging.** [Apple doesn't make a distinction on wireless and wired charging for their 80% battery capacity at 500 cycles claim](https://www.apple.com/batteries/service-and-recycling/).

However, wireless charging may change your charging habits, which can have an effect on battery health.

Wireless charging can make it easier to charge your device by allowing you to simply set your device down, which can lead to your phone [keeping a full charge for longer, which can be bad for your device](https://lifehacker.com/is-it-safe-to-leave-my-smartphone-on-my-wireless-charge-1834138691). [**The sweet spot for battery health is keeping the charge between 20% to 80%**](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/how-to-improve-battery-life-tips-myths-smartphones). Keeping your phone fully charged has the generally same effect on battery health regardless of charging method, wireless or wired.

(Anecdotally, my charging habits have changed due to wireless charging. I have placed wireless chargers by places that I tend to sit down for long periods of time, like my desk at work, on my night table, coffee table, in a car dock, and others. In the past, I wouldn't plug in my phone in these locations, except at night or in the car. My phone now stays on a charger and at 100% for much of the day.)

Comment: *Nearly the same effect*?  What is the difference between the electrons sent to a Lithium battery that are generated from an induction coil within the iPhone and the electrons sourced outside the phone (power adapter)?

Comment: @Allan As I state in the last paragraph, differences in charging speed and heating between wireless and wired charging *could* have an effect on battery health.

Comment: *Charging speed* and *heat*?   No.  If speed, which is determined by amperage, were a factor, it would mean “rapid chargers” would damage your battery.  Magnetic induction doesn’t generate heat - the movement of electrons across the wire (friction) generates the heat.

Comment: @Allan I have made an edit to my answer to reflect your comments.